# Transferring music from laptop using usb cable

Tags: samsung, file-transfer, music

I tethered my galaxy s9 to my Asus windows laptop.  How do I transfer my.laptops music files to my galaxy memory card?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Usually if you connect the phone via USB there is a notification that leads you to the USB mode chooser where you can enable file transfer mode.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. By "tether", did you mean simply "connected using USB" to the laptop? There's also a term "USB tethering" meaning "sharing internet connecting using a USB cable", but it shouldn't be needed to transfer data from a PC directly using a USB cable.